# Checkbox and Handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I have a checkbox that is outside of my Handsontable. My Handsontable is populated through ajax. I want to hide and show Handsontable columns based on the value of checkbox. This is how my code looks like

```
  Handsontable.dom.addEvent(mycheckbox, 'change', function () {
            var hot = $container.data('handsontable');
            if (mycheckbox.checked) {
                hot.updateSettings({
                    hiddenColumns: {
                        columns: [0],
                        indicators: true
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                hot.updateSettings({
                    hiddenColumns: {
                        columns: [0,1,2],
                        indicators: true
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

This code only executes when you check or uncheck the checkbox and it works fine, but I want to use this code on the page load event also, or when the Handsontable loads.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Handsontable event hooks. `afterLoadData` hook will run a callback after new data is loaded into the data source array. If this isn't the right the place you're looking for you can substitute the hook event with the appropriate hook event as I mentioned earlier with `init`.

so you could just make that function the `afterLoadData` hook's callback

```
var example = document.getElementById('example');
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');

// use event hook and add custom callback
// this will hide column 2 if checkbox is initially checked on 
// page load
Handsontable.hooks.add("afterLoadData", function() {

  if (checkbox.checked) {
      this.updateSettings({
        hiddenColumns: {
          columns: [2],
          indicators: true
        }
      })
    } else {
      this.updateSettings({
        hiddenColumns: {
          columns: [1],
          indicators: true
        }
      })
    }

});
```

Here's [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/vuhijeyaki/edit?html,js,console,output) of it in action

Comment: Where on the page should I call it?

Comment: the same place you define your Handsontable

Comment: Can you show us some example. Also how will this check the value of checkbox

Comment: Any one please help

Comment: @Naeem is the jsbin I added what you need?

Comment: ok its not working for me. I can see the alert but the columns are not getting hidden

 Handsontable.hooks.add("afterLoadData", function () {
            alert('I am in');
            this.updateSettings({
                hiddenColumns: {
                    columns: [0],
                    indicators: true
                }
            })
        });